# Error 404 al Pasar valor de POST de HTML a PHP en la misma página

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Cordial saludo. Lo que necesito hacer es algo muy sencillo. Es pasar el valor del POST de HTML a una variable PHP ($name). Lo que ocurre es que tengo un evento action que hace que recargue datos en la misma página y me genera un conflicto que redirecciona a una página 404 cuando le doy al botón submit de "Consultar". El action debe apuntar a la misma página pero no se por qué en Wordpress no me lo reconoce así.

Envío el código que tengo hasta el momento (Agregando una función javascript que captura el value del select):

```
<script>
function test() {
    d = document.getElementById("lista").value;
    return d;
}
</script>

<div>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
       <div>
            Seleccione periodo: 
            <select onchange="test()" name="name" id="lista">
                <option value="0" selected>Haga clic aquí</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['name']=='1') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>> ENERO</option>
                <option value="2"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='2') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>FEBRERO</option>
                <option value="3"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='3') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MARZO</option>
                <option value="4"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='4') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>ABRIL</option>
                <option value="5"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='5') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>MAYO</option>
                <option value="6"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='6') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JUNIO</option>
                <option value="7"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='7') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>JULIO</option>
                <option value="8"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='8') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>AGOSTO</option>
                <option value="9"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='9') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>SEPTIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="10"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='10') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>OCTUBRE</option>
                <option value="11"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='11') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>NOVIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="12"  <?php if($_POST['name']=='12') echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>DICIEMBRE</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Consultar">
            <input type="button" onclick=" generateexcel('testTable') " value="Exportar a Excel">
        </div>
     </form>
</div>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{  
$name = $_POST['name'];
}
echo "No encontrado";
?>
```

Comment: ajax al rescate !!!

Comment: la solución rápida es ajax. Sin embargo, tu pregunta es muy abierta, no aclaras a dónde va la variable, a quién se le debe asignar, etc.. Dudo que alguien pueda ayudare con código con una pregunta tan amplia

Comment: la variable captura en onchange el valor del select y debe ser enviada a una variable PHP llamada $name que está después del select

Comment: te marca algún error en los log?

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el javascript con el que manejas la acción del botón Consultar? Aunque si quieres mostrar resultados en la misma página ajax es la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Comment: te consta que el valor de `action` apunta a la url correcta, en la carpeta correcta?

Comment: No muestra error en los log, sólo un warning más abajo porque utiliza lo que trae POST en una variable $name y no encuentra ni la variable ni el valor. No sé cómo pasar valores desde javascript con ajax y no quisiera complicarme más puesto que esto mismo funcionaba en Joomla. El action debe apuntar a la misma página pero aunque use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; sigue redireccionando a la 404.

Comment: Ya agregué una función javascript para capturar el value del select, péro cómo lo paso con ajax a php?

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de utilizar`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` deberías dirigir el formulario a la url que te asigna Worldpress para ésta página. Eso o puedes utilizar un iframe para que funcione tu código como lo tienes escrito.

Comment: Y cómo obtendo esa url?

Comment: Aparece en la barra de tu navegador cuando visitas esa página en especial.

Comment: Esta función te ayudará a obtener la URL cómo la quieres. <br/>`function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}`<br/> La forma de utilizarlo sería la siguiente: `echo curPageURL();`

Answer (score 1):

En un form, cuando colocas un action vacío:

```
<form action="">
```

se interpreta que el post se hará sobre la misma url. No necesitas buscar la url correcta, sólo dejar que el navegador se busque la vida él solo.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega `return false;` después de llamar la función `generateexcel`:

```
<input
    type="button"
    onclick="generateexcel('testTable'); return false;"
    value="Exportar a Excel"
>
```